# match strings typed and parsed from json android

Tags: android, json, string

trying to write an if statement that checks if "what i typed" is equal to string got from json object.
something like this:

```
String test = jsonObject.getString(tag); //gets "posao" from json
Log.e("from json", test);
Log.e("typed", "posao");

if (test=="posao"){
//do something..
}
```

and in logcat it looks like a match but in reality..no :(

```
01-04 12:21:19.320: E/from json(21774): posao
01-04 12:21:19.320: E/typed(21774): posao
```

how can i get it to match?

Comment: `if (test.equals("posao")){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `equals` to compare strings instead of `==`. Because if you use `==` you compare links instead of data. So a right way is

```
if(test.equals("posao")){

// Do what you need

}
```

Answer (score 1):

use **equals()** function.

```
 if(test.equals("posao"))
 {
Log.d("String","equal");
}
```

or you can also use

```
if (0 == test.compareTo("posao"))
{
Log.d("String","equal");
}
```